# hub browse with Ruby 2.7.1

Tags: ruby, terminal

Since I update to Ruby 2.7.1 I can't use `hub browse` in the terminal.
Don't know why.
I got this message :

```
rbenv: hub: command not found

The `hub' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.6.5
```

Do I have to re-install hub with `brew install hub`?

Comment: There’s about ten billion results on google for “hub.” What is hub?

Comment: it complains about ruby 2.6.5 and not 2.7.1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the RubyGem [hub](https://rubygems.org/gems/hub/versions/1.12.4), you need to install it for every Ruby version. You can do this with `gem`:

```
gem install hub
```

Comment: Thanks Ana Maria it's works.
It was so weird because `hub borwse` was only working for some folders.
Now with `gem install hub` everything seems in order.
Thanks again 